# I think we still need to practice some more

Tags: determiners, adverbial-phrases

We all know here 'some more' used as an 'adverb':

> Would you like **some more** cake?
>
> I think we still need to practice some more.
>
> If the rice is still not cooked, add **some more water**.
>
> Would you like **some more potatoes**?
>
> I need to work on it some more.

I wonder how 'some more' used as an 'adverb' can be placed before noun in bold sentence.  Is it grammatical?

I conclude that 'more' is likely to be an adjective and then 'some' can be used as an 'adverb' on above examples.

Comment: You've got the analysis wrong, "Some more" is not an adverb; it is a DP (determinative phrase) in which "more" is a determinative modified by the determinative "some".

Answer (score 2):

In

i.  He walked more rapidly.

*rapidly* is an adverb modifying the verb *walked*, and 
*more* is an adverb modifying the adverb *rapidly*.

In

ii. We still need to practice some more

*more* is an adverb modifying the verb *to practice*, and
*some* is an adverb modifying the adverb *more*.

As you recognize, *more* can be either an adjective or an adverb, so here is
a second way to understand your sentence analyzing *more* as an "adjective":

iii.  We need to do some more [something].

In *iii*, *[something]* could be eating, drinking, talking, practicing -- any "gerund" understood to have been derived from the main verb.

Comment: I wouldn't go along with you here. "Some" is not an adverb; it is a determinative modifying the determinative "more". "Some more" is thus a DP (determinative phrase) marking the noun ("cake", "water", "potatoes") as indefinite.

Comment: Well, we could also call *some* a quantifier.  I took Mickey's question to be how/whether *more* could be an adjective and/or an adverb, and let him keep his analysis of *some* as "adverb".

Comment: Yes, the determinative "more" has to do with quantification, but it is not an adjective or an adverb. "Some" is also a determinative; in this case it is modifying "more". Together they form the DP "some more".

Comment: @BillJ Seems to me that you have a useful and helpful answer to contribute here, and I can't figure out why you don't write it.

Answer (score 0):

*More* is not an adverb in the first sentence.

> I think we still need to practice some more.

*more* is a pronoun  (the direct object of *practice*)

*some* is a called a determiner by some resources (see Oxford dictionary) and an adjective by others (American Heritage). See below for links.

> Would you like some more cake?

When you actually name the noun, then *more* is a determiner; some resources consider it an adjective. ([American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=More) for one)

*Some* becomes a determiner or, a predeterminer.

If you have *some* only, as in

> Would you like some?

*some* is a pronoun, or noun

See Oxford dictionary

[more](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/more)

[some](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/some)

American Heritage:
[some](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Some)

Answer (score -1):

Note that "more" can be either an adjective or an adverb, depending on how it's used.  Also note that an adverb can either precede or follow a verb:

> They quickly drove to the store
>
> They drove quickly to the store

Although it's probably not good *style*, an adverb can commonly appear far away from the verb:

> They drove to the store quickly.

So in your examples, even though "some more" appears before a noun, it's not immediately clear whether it modifies the verb, or the following noun.

> Would you like some more cake?

How much do you *want*?" Some more. **Or**, "How much *cake* do you want?" Some more.

> If the rice is still not cooked, add some more water.

"How much do I *add*?"  Some more. **Or**, "How much *water* do I add?" Some more.

> I need to work on it some more.

"How much do you need to *work*?"  Some more. **Or**, "How much do you need to work on *it*?  Some more.

Either way works.  It just depends on what part of the sentence you choose to emphasize.

Ultimately, remember that labeling parts of speech, in any language, is only an artificial *exercise* designed to help with comprehension.  What's more important is how well you can *communicate* in that language.

Comment: Some" is not an adverb; it is a determinative modifying the determinative "more". "Some more" is thus a DP (determinative phrase) marking the noun ("cake", "water", "potatoes") as indefinite.

Comment: @BillJ "More" is an adverb, or at least it can be.  In the sentence "I want more" is it acting as an adjective or an adverb?  Is it modifying "want" or some unspoken direct object?  Honestly, it seems like it could go either way, so perhaps there's some kind of in-between part of speech you'd call it?

Comment: Adverbs typically modify verbs and adjectives, not nouns. In "I want more", "more" is a fused determiner-head where the determiner and the head of the NP are fused together (cf, "I want more cake")

Comment: @BillJ and Andrew Something to think about: *We talked, and talked, and talked some more.* (I'm not going to say what this *some more* is, but my point is sometimes, or actually most of the time, it's not the most important thing for learners to be able to tell what exactly a part of a sentence is.)

Comment: +1 @DamkerngT. Right you are! This OP needs first to understand what the gallumphing ramdoozle is _working on:_ the noun or the verb. Only after that is clear he can profitably move to what it's called, and why.